# Use new customer attributes in shopping cart price rules - offi_customer_attributes_manager

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

This is not about "custom attributes". It is about using new customer attributes in shopping cart price rules. Means attributes related to a customer not a product.

We added some customer attributes with help of the Extension "offi_customer_attributes_manager".

Is there a way to use the added customer attributes in the shopping cart rules? eg. the customer attribute "company" can be used to apply a rule only for customers which have a specific customer attribute value?

I searched a lot but could not even find someone who has the same problem.

Comment: I found this Googling for this same exact need. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No we did find no solution and skipped it.